# Got lldb error while assigning value for heightconstraint.constant

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have created a height constraint and i am assigning a value to it according to the screen size. But while assigning I get the error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` on the line `heightConstraint.constant = Height`

```
var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
let Height =((intra_acc_send_b.frame.origin.y+intra_acc_send_b.frame.size.height)+20)

print ("\nheight%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ") ; print(Height); print(" %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\n");
heightConstraint.constant = Height 
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: Width,  height: heightConstraint.constant )
```

Kindly help me to find out the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

heightConstraint is nil and you are accessing it that why that error is. In swift 4.2 Implicitly Force Unwrapping has been abolish. So if you check heightConstraint it will give optional value even though its ImplicitlyForceWapped if it has value.

You need to Optional binding to unwrapped safely either using `if let` or `guard` before assigning new value.

```
if let constraints = heightConstraint {
    heightConstraint.constant = Height 
}
```

or

```
guard let constraints =  heightConstraint else { return }
heightConstraint.constant = Height
```

Your view is not created yet that's why height is not yet there.

Comment: I have created the view and the height gets printed as 441.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have never initialized `heightConstraint` (it's `nil`). 
You need to initialize it first.

If the `heightConstraint` is `@IBOutlet`, you need to run this code in `viewDidLoad` or later.

Answer (score 0):

Take care of these lines:

```
print ("\nheight%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ") ; print(Height); print(" %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\n");
heightConstraint.constant = Height 
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: Width,  height: heightConstraint.constant )
```

Depending on type of class you are using:

**In ViewController**

Have them after or during

```
viewDidLoad
```

**In a view**

Have them after or during

```
awakeFromNib
```